# AngularJS Wait the last loading of an item before execute a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-promise

I'm stuck on a problem on AngularJs and I can't solve it. (I'm a newbie on Angular).

I have a container directive, a page directive and a contents directive.

```html
<container>
  <page>
    <contents></contents>
  </page>
  <page></page>
  <page></page>
  <!-- ... -->
</container>
```

On each page, the link function appends 1 to the number of pages of the MasterService (a factory)

```js
app.directive('page', function(Master) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            Master.pages ++;
        }
    }
});
```

This code works however, when the contents function is called (this function will be on the 1st or the 2nd page) to get Master.page, I only get 1 or 2 because the next pages weren't analysed. The only way I found is to do a $timeout when I want to get Master.pages

```js
$timeout(function() {
  console.log(Master.pages);
}, 2000);
```

But I don't like that, how can I call a function after all the pages were loaded ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your are using transclusion the order of compile, pre-link and post-link is changed. (see Angular docs)

Instead of using link try to use compile like here: This way your counter will be incremented in the pre-link phase.

```js
app.directive('page', function(Master) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        compile: function(tElem, tAttrs){
        
        return {
          pre: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
            Master.pages ++;
          },
          post: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
            
          }
        }
      }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just want to provide an alternative thought from @user1802646's.

How are you generating the pages? If they are data driven, can you use ng-repeat? You maybe able to make user of "ng-repeat-end" to achieve the correct timing you want.